# What is current date of LaTeX2e format?

Tags: pdftex, format-files

My preamble begins with a line like the following, so as to help ensure that the version of LaTeX being used is sufficiently new:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2022-11-01]
```

How do I determine the date of the current LaTeX format? For example, what doc file in TeXLive do I consult, etc.?

I had for that line originally `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2022-12-01]` but when compiling my source, I see warning that the available format (with all files up-to-date via TeX Live Utility) is only `2022-11-01`. Where does the latex command find that date?

**Added:**

I am actually using the development version `pdflatex-dev` of `pdflatex`, and the log of a run begins thus:

```
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2023-2-2 branch)
L3 programming layer <2023-02-01>
```

In such a case, what date-like string should I use in the `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[202x-xx-xx]` command?

Comment: It's not a date, it's an identifier that looks like a date ...

Comment: @JosephWright: But how.where does the 'pdflatex` command, e.g., find or determine that date, and how can I find it from the distributed TeXLive files? (I not that `pdflatex --version` does *not* show it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The version string (not actually a date: we pick something nominal and memorable) is printed as part of a LaTeX run in the `.log` and at the terminal

```
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-01-24>
```

This string is part of the sources of LaTeX: the extracted version is `latex.ltx`, or in the sources in `ltvers.dtx`. (The printed line comes from the format file: a pre-compiled memory dump of the TeX engine when `latex.ltx` has been read.)

---

Note that the `dev` branch has a nominal date in the future. For example, the current pre-release says

```latex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2023-1-30 branch)
```

which would go down as `2023-06-01` as the target next release date. The branch information is primarily for the LaTeX team's reference.

Comment: Please see the Added comment re `pdflatex-dev` in my question.

Comment: So which date-like string should I use in `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}` to request the `dev` branch in question: `2023-06-01` or `2023-02-01`?

Comment: @murray `2023-06-01` which would (today) give an error if used with pdflatex but no error with pdflatex-dev

Comment: @murray What David said, but I'm wondering what your use case is - the dev formats are for testing by interested users/developers, and the entire point is this is code not yet ready for general use

Comment: @JosephWright: I'm using the dev version so as to be able to exploit inclusion of as much document metadata as possible. (Am I mistaken in using `pdflatex-dev` for that?)

Comment: @murray for production use use pdflatex, if you want to test beta releases of the next latex release use pdflatex-dev, so it's a bit unusual to `\NeedsTeXFormat` so that only beta releases may be used.